# How to use a loop with if statements to execute until the loops condition is met in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Appreciate any answers to this conumdrum in advance !

I have a function to generate password which takes in a number of options chosen by a user via prompts and confirms - one of these prompts returns a password length and all these options are stored within an options object i get access to using dot notation within this function.

I need to generate a bunch of characters which have been determined by the users choices - it needs to be only the length the user has entered in the prompt.

In this case i've decided to have a loop where a password lengths condition is met and at each iteration the body of the if statement should execute a getRandom function which will return a single random character from array passed to it as an argument to function.

However on testing my code - i can not get the if statements to only execute only the number of times the user has entered as the password length.

How do i achieve this with a while loop or any other loop.

```
function generatePassword() {

  const optSelected = getPasswordOptions();

  let generatedPassArr = [];

  const passwordLength = optSelected.passwordLength;

  let counter = 0;
  let lowercaseCounted;
  let uppercaseCounted;
  let numbersCounted;
  let specialsCounted;

  while (counter < passwordLength) {
    if (optSelected.lowercase && !lowercaseCounted) {
      console.log("execute random function lowercase");
      lowercaseCounted = true;
    } else {
      break;
    }

    if (optSelected.uppercase && !uppercaseCounted) {
      console.log("execute random function uppercase");
      uppercaseCounted = true;
    }

    if (optSelected.numbers && !numbersCounted) {
      console.log("execute random function numbers");
      numbersCounted = true;
    }

    if (optSelected.specials && !specialsCounted) {
      console.log("execute random function specials");
      specialsCounted = true;
    }

    console.log("testing");

    counter++;
  }

  console.log(generatedPassArr);
}
```

As you can see i have attempted to create variables so that each if statement does not repeat continously in a block - rather i need atleast the if block to execute once - if the object property exists true,  until the loop reaches the password length.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific need to use a `while` loop here (i.e. this is an assignment) have you considered using regex to test this instead?

With a singular regex for each password criteria, I think you could avoid the use of the `while` loop altogether.

Comment: thanks for the response, there is no particular need to use the while loop - i thought of using the while loop to return the characters based on the password length.  How would i use regex here to do the same. thanks